# Python dataframe, looking up values for specific index number

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe with daily stock price data for different stocks. The index is a consecutive number. In the column 'index_high' I have the index number, for a day in which a special event happened. 
What I need is a new column 'high_price', which gives me the price data for the index of the index number in 'index_high'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DO5o.png)

So in this example I would get the price, that occurs in line 99757 as an output in column 'high_price' in line 99995 until 99999

I can't figure it out, how to build the for loop here. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Try consulting the docs and see if they clear this up first: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Comment: Please see if what I have done helps. If it doesn't, shout out, we will help

Comment: _I can't figure it out, how to build the for loop here._ Please be more specific. Stack Overflow is not a substitute for guides, tutorials, or documentation, see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 0):

Data

```
 df=pd.DataFrame({'index':[95,96,97,98,99],'index_high':[69,82,58,67,54]})
    df.set_index('index', inplace=True)
```

Many ways to do this. But try [aggregating](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) over the specified axis

```
df['max']=df.index_high.agg('max')
```